# How to transform a sealed Kotlin class into a Java class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent in Java code for this kotlin sealed class

```
sealed class Resource<out T> {
    class Loading<out T> : Resource<T>()
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Resource<T>()
    data class Failure<out T>(val exception: Exception) : Resource<T>()
}
```

Comment: How about `Tools` -> `Kotlin` -> `Show Kotlin Bytecode` -> `Decompile to Java` ?

Comment: I have done that but the decompile java code does not look for something I expect

Comment: `sealed class` is nothing more than an `abstract class` with additional compile time constraints (declare all inheriting classes in same file, ability to fill out "when" cases) which are not present in java.

Comment: The Kotlin uses `DefaultConstructorMarker` class (from `kotlin.jvm.internal`) as an argument to sealed class that is private in that package, and passes null to that ever time a class extend it. You cannot replicate the behavior because the code won't compile if you try to access private final class from different package than you are at. Kotlin manages to do this because it is compiled from Kotlin compiler that does not interfere with Java compiler. You can however replicate it by making these classes into a package and make a private class, which cannot be accessed by any other package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like that (unfortunately, too verbose):

```
class Resource<T> {
    class Loading extends Resource<T> { }
    class Success extends Resource<T> {

        @NonNull
        T data;

        public Success(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    class Failure extends Resource<T> {

        @NonNull
        Exception exception;

        public Failure(Exception exception) {
            this.exception = exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner classes should be marked `static` or you won't be able to instantiate them without having an instance of the parent class. And to really match sealed classes, the parent should be abstract. When this is used in Java, it won't have the main feature of sealed classes: using them in an exhaustive `when` expression.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use in my Java project:

```
public class State<T> {
    // States, use enums if possible
    public static final int INITIAL = 0;
    public static final int LOADING = 1;
    public static final int SUCCESS = 2;
    public static final int ERROR = 3;

    private final int type;
    private final T data;
    private final Throwable error;

    private State(@NonNull int type, @Nullable T d, @Nullable Throwable e) {
        this.type = type;
        this.data = d;
        this.error = e;
    }

    public static <T> State<T> initial() {
        return new State<>(INITIAL, null, null);
    }

    public static <T> State<T> loading() {
        return new State<>(LOADING, null, null);
    }

    public static <T> State<T> success(T d) {
        return new State<>(SUCCESS, d, null);
    }

    public static <T> State<T> error(Throwable e) {
        return new State<>(ERROR, null, e);
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Throwable getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Augusto, I have also used this one

```
public class StateData<T> {

    @NonNull
    private DataStatus status;

    @Nullable
    private T data;

    @Nullable
    private Throwable error;

    public StateData() {
        this.status = DataStatus.CREATED;
        this.data = null;
        this.error = null;
    }

    public StateData<T> loading() {
        this.status = DataStatus.LOADING;
        this.data = null;
        this.error = null;
        return this;
    }

    public StateData<T> success(@NonNull T data) {
        this.status = DataStatus.SUCCESS;
        this.data = data;
        this.error = null;
        return this;
    }

    public StateData<T> error(@NonNull Throwable error) {
        this.status = DataStatus.ERROR;
        this.data = null;
        this.error = error;
        return this;
    }

    public StateData<T> complete() {
        this.status = DataStatus.COMPLETE;
        return this;
    }

    @NonNull
    public DataStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @Nullable
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Nullable
    public Throwable getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public enum DataStatus {
        CREATED,
        SUCCESS,
        ERROR,
        LOADING,
        COMPLETE
    }
}
```

Comment: may I know how you use this in java?